# Entity Framework 6 Log - SQL Profiler

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-6, sql-server-profiler

I have enable EF 6 Log Functionality into my application:

```
// Add loggin (DEVELOPMENT ONLY)
DbContext.Database.Log = logInfo => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(logInfo);
```

Its working fine but I see like repeated SQL Queries in my Console, so I opened a SQL Profiler and saw the following:

[image]

There is a **SQL: BatchStarting** and **SQL: BatchCompleted** any clue what does that mean? Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just means that **one** SQL batch has started and completed.

So,

- **SQL: BatchStarting**: an SQL statement/batch has started.
- **SQL: BatchCompleted**: that same SQL statement/batch has been completed.

That way you can eg: measure the time needed to execute that specific SQL statement/batch.

This does **not** mean that two different SQL statements has been executed.

Comment: so Database is only hit once?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL:BatchStarting event class indicates that a Transact-SQL batch is starting directly from the site [MSDN/Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190441.aspx) more [detailed writeup](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/272/profiler-and-server-side-traces/)